# Netty client bounded queue discard policy

Tags: netty

Hitting an OutMemoryError connecting to 3rd party server which cannot process requests fast enough.

Tried NioClientSocketChannelFactory to pass in the executor service with the bounded queue and discard policy (ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy) but still got OutOfMemoryError.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your client-side Netty channel's write buffer fills up and the server is not reading it fast enough, you will see `OutOfMemoryError` on the client side.  To avoid that, you have to stop writing if `Channel.isWritable()` returns `false`.  You will be notified with a `channelInterestOpsChanged` event when the status of `Channel.writable' changes.  Then, you can check again if`Channel.isWritable()`returns`true` and continue writing.

If it is OK to discard the pending data, I would simply not call `Channel.write()` if `Channel.isWritable()` returns `false`.

You can configure when `Channel.writable` property changes with the watermark properties provided in `NioSocketChannelConfig`.  Also, please take a look into the 'discard' example that uses this technique.

Comment: Seems to have worked. By the way should I bother using bounded worker pool or just use the cached one thats is used in the samples?

Thanks

Comment: Worker pool must be the cached one.

Comment: Any particular reason why it must? And if it must, then why leave the option to change it? Just curious now hehe

Comment: Wouldn't it be sensible if Netty automatically backed off? There's no risk in doing a timed wait here since we're already putting enough pressure on the system.